# PowerShell: ConvertTo-Html not respecting string, instead counting characters

Tags: powershell

Thanks for any input, I'm writing a report and trying to compile the results into HTML for readability.  I'm trying to re-write some components to result in higher readability.  The problem seems to be associated with the conversion of data into HTML (via ConvertTo-Html).

**Question**
How can I properly convert the string variable into HTML to compile in my report?

**Code**

```
    # Querying specified event log for errors within the last 30 days
    $time = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))
    $securityeventviewer = Get-WmiObject win32_ntlogevent -ComputerName SERVERNAME -ErrorAction Stop |
    Where-Object {($_.logfile -eq 'Security' -and $_.type -eq 'error' -and $_.timegenerated -ge $time)} |
    Select-Object @{n='ErrorTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)}}, Category, EventCode, EventIdentifier, Type, Message |
    Sort-Object EventIdentifier -unique <#|
    ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Security Event Log</h2>'#>

if ($securityeventviewer -eq $null){
    $securityeventviewer = 'NO SECURITY ERRORS'

    }

else {
    $securityeventviewer = $securityEventViewer
    }

$securityeventviewer | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

**Result**
It appears to be the properties of the variable, not the actual string:

```
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Expected Result**
NO SECURITY ERRORS

I've seen some posts that seem similar, but nothing exactly matching this question. It appears to be with the fact I'm trying to convert a string to HTML, but I don't know what I should do as a workaround.
*The $securityeventviewer variable does have a value of NO SECURITY ERRORS, so I know the conversion is where the issue is occurring*

Thanks in advance for your responses!

**UPDATED WORKING CODE TO CHECK**

```
    # Querying specified event log for errors within the last 30 days
$time = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))
$securityeventviewer = Get-WmiObject win32_ntlogevent -ComputerName AUGURSERVER2k16 -ErrorAction Stop |
    Where-Object {($_.logfile -eq 'Security' -and $_.type -eq 'error' -and $_.timegenerated -ge $time)} |
    Select-Object @{n='ErrorTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)}}, Category, EventCode, EventIdentifier, Type, Message |
    Sort-Object EventIdentifier -unique

if ($securityeventviewer -eq $null){
    #If SQL instance and server don't match produce this result
    $securityeventviewer = "NO SECURITY ERRORS" |
    ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Type NoteProperty -Name Security -Value $_; $_} |
    Select Security |
    ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Security Event Log</h2>'
    }

else {
$securityeventviewer = Get-WmiObject win32_ntlogevent -ComputerName AUGURSERVER2k16 -ErrorAction Stop |
    Where-Object {($_.logfile -eq 'Security' -and $_.type -eq 'error' -and $_.timegenerated -ge $time)} |
    Select-Object @{n='ErrorTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)}}, Category, EventCode, EventIdentifier, Type, Message |
    Sort-Object EventIdentifier -unique |
    ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Security Event Log</h2>'
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
# Querying specified event log for errors within the last 30 days
$securityEventViewer = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ([datetime]::Today).AddDays(-30) -EntryType Error -ComputerName AUGURSERVER2k16 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Select-Object TimeGenerated, CategoryNumber, EventID, Index, EntryType, Message |
Sort-Object Index -unique

$output = $(
if($securityEventViewer -eq $null){ 
    [PSCustomObject]@{'security' = "NO SECURITY ERRORS"} 
} else { 
    $securityEventViewer 
}
) 
write-host $output
```

Comment: The `else` in your `if` statement is superfluous.

Comment: Ha, good point, thanks for that quick tidbit.  Obviously doesn't change the functionality, but appreciate another pair of eyes cleaning things up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ConvertTo-HTML` is designed to convert .Net objects to HTML, not simple strings.

You may need to do something like:

```
if ($securityeventviewer -eq $null){
    $securityeventviewer = 'NO SECURITY ERRORS'
    "<p>$securityeventviewer</p>"
    }

else {
    $securityeventviewer | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment
    }
```

My HTML is not strong, so the `<p></p>` may be wrong, but the idea is sound, so that if you get no results you output a HTML fragment of your own design, but if there are results then PowerShell will convert those results to a HTML table for you.

**Edit:** Ok, assuming that you can use `Get-EventLog` instead of having to do a WMIC call to get the event logs, you should be able to shorten the code that you have above to this:

```
# Querying specified event log for errors within the last 30 days
$SecurityEventViewer = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ([datetime]::Today).AddDays(-30) -EntryType Error -ComputerName AUGURSERVER2k16 |
Select-Object TimeGenerated, CategoryNumber, EventID, Index, EntryType, Message |
Sort-Object Index -unique

$Output = $(
    if($securityeventviewer -eq $null){ 
        [PSCustomObject]@{'security' = "NO SECURITY ERRORS"} 
    } else { 
        $securityeventviewer 
    }
) | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Security Event Log</h2>'
```

Now, that saves your HTML fragment in the `$Output` variable instead of re-using the `$securityeventviewer` variable. It is also using the built in command `Get-EventLog`, and making the event log provider filter the results before sending them across the network instead of getting all events from every log from the remote computer, and then filtering them all after the fact in PowerShell. It should go quite a bit faster than what you have, unless your WMIC call is really that much faster than the built in command. If your WMIC query really is faster then I would have WMIC filter the results, and that should be even faster yet.

Comment: So I following something similar and have it working, but it may be redundant and need cleaned up.  I'm open to you guys chiming in on any best practice ideas. --see original for update.

Comment: Yeah, your code needs some cleanup. Is there a reason that you aren't using `Get-EventLog`?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  When trying your code I receive an" if : The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling....  At line:12 char:5, then references the 'if' in the 'if($securityEventViewer -eq $null){

Comment: Also, I wasn't using Get-EventLog because of the additional filtering I was originally performing.  I was actually lumping all the event logs together at first, then decided against it.  I'm not opposed to using Get-EventLog whatsoever, it simply didn't fit my original needs.  This appears to not be the case any longer :)

Comment: UPDATE: Okay I think I got it, you need to to insert a $ surrounding the entire if block.  I'm updating the code above under the edit section of the original question.  Take a look.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Marked it as the correct answer :)  Thanks for the quick help, much appreciated!!!